# How do I read low energy bluetooth serial with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using  [plugin](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial) for reading bluetooth serial data in phonegap. But unfortunately this plugin supports only classic bluetooth on android side, any ideas how can I read serial data from low energy bluetooth on android?

Comment: Are you able to do this using native Android (Java?). If yes, then it's a matter of writing a plugin for PhoneGap to communicate back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the one for ios should give you some ideas to get started https://github.com/KristinaHeyerdahlElfving/Bluetooth-Smart-Plugin